# Downloading Json FIle using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mxgraph

This is my json data that I currently get when i convert a xml file:

```
{"mxGraphModel":{"root":{"mxCell":[{"_id":"0"},{"_id":"1","_parent":"0"},{"mxGeometry":{"_x":"200","_y":"100","_width":"100","_height":"100","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"2","_style":"shape=ellipse","_vertex":"1","_parent":"1"},{"mxGeometry":{"_x":"520","_y":"250","_width":"100","_height":"100","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"3","_style":"shape=triangle","_vertex":"1","_parent":"1"},{"mxGeometry":{"_x":"900","_y":"460","_width":"100","_height":"100","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"4","_style":"shape=cylinder","_vertex":"1","_parent":"1"},{"mxGeometry":{"_x":"310","_y":"450","_width":"100","_height":"100","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"5","_style":"shape=actor","_vertex":"1","_parent":"1"},{"mxGeometry":{"_relative":"1","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"6","_edge":"1","_parent":"1","_source":"2","_target":"3"},{"mxGeometry":{"_relative":"1","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"7","_edge":"1","_parent":"1","_source":"5","_target":"3"},{"mxGeometry":{"_relative":"1","_as":"geometry"},"_id":"8","_edge":"1","_parent":"1","_source":"3","_target":"4"}]}}}
```

But when I download the same data as .json, I get this:

```
"{\"mxGraphModel\":{\"root\":{\"mxCell\":[{\"_id\":\"0\"},{\"_id\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"0\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_x\":\"200\",\"_y\":\"100\",\"_width\":\"100\",\"_height\":\"100\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"2\",\"_style\":\"shape=ellipse\",\"_vertex\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_x\":\"520\",\"_y\":\"250\",\"_width\":\"100\",\"_height\":\"100\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"3\",\"_style\":\"shape=triangle\",\"_vertex\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_x\":\"900\",\"_y\":\"460\",\"_width\":\"100\",\"_height\":\"100\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"4\",\"_style\":\"shape=cylinder\",\"_vertex\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_x\":\"310\",\"_y\":\"450\",\"_width\":\"100\",\"_height\":\"100\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"5\",\"_style\":\"shape=actor\",\"_vertex\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_relative\":\"1\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"6\",\"_edge\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\",\"_source\":\"2\",\"_target\":\"3\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_relative\":\"1\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"7\",\"_edge\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\",\"_source\":\"5\",\"_target\":\"3\"},{\"mxGeometry\":{\"_relative\":\"1\",\"_as\":\"geometry\"},\"_id\":\"8\",\"_edge\":\"1\",\"_parent\":\"1\",\"_source\":\"3\",\"_target\":\"4\"}]}}}"
```

I find that there are unwanted "\" characters in the downloaded version. The code i use to download the data is:

```
function download(jFile) {
 var text = jFile;
 var result = "data:application/json," + encodeURI(text);
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 a.style = "display: none";
 a.href = result;
 a.download = "flowChartJson.json";
 if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== undefined) {
   window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, a.download);
 window.URL.revokeObjectURL(result);
   return;
 }
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 requestAnimationFrame(function() {
   a.click();
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(result);
   document.body.removeChild(a);
 });
```

}

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: It looks like at some point the data is being double-encoded - i.e. a string which is already a JSON string is being encoded again as JSON. It's not clear where this is happening. Check the content of your `jFile` data and see if it's already corrupted by that point or not, that will narrow down the issue to being either inside or outside the function you've shown.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. the code seems to work perfectly now.